# Magento 2 plan - zip code preselect - time slots - hiding products for location

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, zipcode, customize, delivery-date

I need help with a customized magento 2 webshop. We have custom plan, and I don't know which is the good way.

*note: We're developers, so custom module development is not a problem*

So my plan is (workflow of the user)

- User can preselect Zip code or city in cart, or with a popup - but without login (so we need to store in in session I think - custom module I think)
- If user is located, we can hide several products which is not available in the user's location (here is a question - should we set store views, or customer groups, or shipping method or custom module or something other based on session)
- User put some products in the cart, and goes to checkout.
- On checkout user can select delivery time slots (our plan is to use [amasty's delivery plugin](https://amasty.com/delivery-date-for-magento-2.html))
- Time slots should depend on location (amasty plugin supports only different time slots per store views, but customer group or shipping method can be solved as well)

I think that's all. :)

I've googled a lot, but I can't find any plan or plugin for this, I think it's a custom idea, but I don't want to work twice, so I have to plan it thoroughly.

Thanks for you help, I hope we can find the perfect solution :)

Bye
Adam

Answer (score 0):

thanks for considering our extension. 
Do you have multiple warehouses? If so, this extension may solve some of your questions https://amasty.com/multi-warehouse-inventory-for-magento-2.html.